# Delay Busy/Loading Indicator During $http Request

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to implement a very simple Loading directive during **$http** requests. I want to add a delay, which means that if the promise is returned within a specified time say 1 sec, the indicator is simply **not shown** to prevent flicker. And it shows only if request/promise takes more than 1 sec. I have tried using **$timout** as:

```
if (_delay) {
    $timeout(function () {
        scope.$root.ShowOverlay = true;
    }, 1000);
}
```

But it won't help as I know. How can i accomplish this? I have setup this [plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/5rPX2WVrh1nciK9ClAfh?p=preview) .

Since my directive stays out of ngView. I am using $rootScope and controller to update rootScope parameter **"OverlayText"**. I would highly appreciate any improvements.

Answer (score 0):

Please don't test syntax :(

```
function getData(){
    $scope.data = null;
    $httpCall("url/properties",functionCallback(response){
        $scope.data = response;
        scope.$root.ShowOverlay = false;
        return $scope.data;
    });
    $timeout(function(){
        if($scope.data != null)
        {
            scope.$root.ShowOverlay = true;
        }
    },1000);
}

getData();
```

Comment: Hi thanx can u update this plunk? https://plnkr.co/edit/M4Nt0ehzYykHGuxXtJRl?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Probably this should be in a service, but in the meantime, this is working for me.

```
myApp.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $http, $rootScope, $timeout) {    
    var getData = function() {
    $rootScope.OverlayText = 'Loading';
    var isLoading = true;
    $timeout(function(){
      isLoading = false;
      $rootScope.ShowOverlay = true;
    },1000);
    $http.get('https://api.github.com/users/potherca/repos?per_page=100', {
        cache: false
      })
      .then(function(_resp) {
        //This timeout is only for testing, not always the response take longer than 1 sec.
        $timeout(function(){
          isLoading = false;
          $scope.datajson = _resp.data;
          $rootScope.ShowOverlay = false;
        },2500);
      });
  }();   

});
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/3bEfka4KQZYoIj0GNgA7?p=preview

Comment: Hi, thanx for your reply, but you probably didn't get my question. It was about delaying the overlay message only if the promise takes more than 1 second. And not delaying the promise itself. Which means I don't want to show any loader if $http returns within 1 sec.

Comment: I put that delay inside the promise because, not always the response take more than 1 second.

Answer (score 0):

I used to work with angular-busy
https://github.com/cgross/angular-busy/blob/master/README.md

On your controller, just provide it with the promise returned from the $http call.
You can also set a "min duration" for it, so it will be shown only if the promise wasn't resolve after 1 sec.
You can also configure template for it, to design your own "loader" indication.

I works really nice for us.

Comment: Ok thnx, let me try it.

Comment: Sure :) Let me know if you need more help. 
If it works for you, don't forget to vote/mark the answer ;)